# Error ts(2322) trying to define a generic function signature in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define an interface like this:

```
interface ColumnGenerator {
  columnName: string;
  columnValuesAsArgs?: string[];
  generator: <T = any[], R = any>(...args: T extends any[] ? T : [T]) => R;
}
```

the value of `generator` should be a function that takes any number of arguments (if any) of any type, and then return something.

But, when I do something like:

```
const generatedColumn: ColumnGenerator = {
  columnName: 'creation_date',
  generator: () => new Date()
}
```

the compiler yields the next error:

```
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'R'.
  'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Date'.
```

I'm fairly new to Typescript, so I don't have an idea of what am I doing wrong here. Could anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: Usually when you get this error, you are using more generic type parameters than you need to. To fulfill the requirement of "a function that takes any number of arguments (if any) of any type, and then return something." you could simply do: `(...args: any[]) => any`. But then Typescript isn't really helping you much... If you post how you intend this function to be used, I may be able to help more with getting the generics right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the value of generator should be a function that takes any number of arguments (if any) of any type, and then return something.

The type that you described here is `(...args: any[]) => any`. That type is a function that takes any number of arguments of `any` type & then returns anything.

```
type ColumnGenerator = {
  columnName: string;
  columnValuesAsArgs?: string[];
  generator: (...args: any[]) => any;
}


const generatedColumn: ColumnGenerator = {
  columnName: 'creation_date',
  generator: () => new Date()
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to constrain things a bit, you could constrain make the `ColumnGenerator` type generic & configure that when it's used:

```
type ColumnGenerator<T = any> = {
  columnName: string;
  columnValuesAsArgs?: string[];
  generator: (...args: any[]) => T;
}

const generatedColumn: ColumnGenerator<Date> = {
  columnName: 'creation_date',
  generator: () => new Date(), // this will now error if `Date` isn't returned from this function
}
```

Comment: Basically, I have another function that will receive an array of `ColumnGenerator` as an argument, then after doing some other stuff, the function will iterate over the array and call the `generator` function, passing the values of the columns listed in `columnValuesAsArgs` as arguments to the `generator`, like:

`for (const column of generatedColumns) {
 const args = [];
 for (const columnValue of column.columnValuesAsArgs || [])
        args.push(row[columnValue]);
    fields.push(column.generator(...args));
}`

PD: Your answer was very helpful, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to carry type information in a type that doesn't support it. In other words, the Interface or type has a static definition, and making an instance of it doesn't change its type.

Think of it this way, If I take in a ColumnGenerator into my function, what is the return type of the generator? There is no way to tell other than to widen it all the way out, and have it be any. As mentioned, you also could make the ColumnGenerator itself generic.

An even simpler way is to just say that the generator itself (any) => any, but then use generics later to be more specific. The key is that the generatedColumn is *not* typed as a ColumnGenerator. It is in fact a more specific type. This allows you to act on the information on the generic later on. Typescript uses structural or "duck" typing. That is, if it quacks like a duck, it is a duck. So if you leave your variables as the exact type they are, you have more information later to use to infer what they acually look like.

For example:

```
type ColumnGenerator = {
  columnName: string;
  columnValuesAsArgs?: string[];
  generator: (...args: any[]) => any;
}

const generatedColumn = {
  columnName: 'creation_date',
  generator: () => new Date()
}

function test<TCol extends ColumnGenerator>(col: TCol): ReturnType<TCol["generator"]> {
    return col.generator();
}

//Date
let t = test(generatedColumn);
```